# Subscribe to Newsletter Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form which includes the input field and submit button.

```
<form class="subscribe">
      <div class="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your e-mail adresss">
        <span>
          <button type="button">Subscribe</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

What is the easiest way to make this functional using front-end only so that when new email is entered I will receive an email with the new signup info. Is this possible with JS/Jquery only?

Comment: nope. not possible. You cannot send emails directly from javascript. You need a mail server to send them

Comment: You want an email to be sent to you from a client's actual **browser**?  If that's what you're after, it's not going to happen, for very good security reasons.  You need server side code for that

Comment: When user enters email and click on subscribe I just want to receive a notification (email) about this new signup.

Comment: In that case, write server-side code.  Javascript will never allow you to send directly from a client's browser.

Comment: First of all, OP should learn the basics of HTTP...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible now! You dont even need javascript/jquery to implement this.

There is a good API Endpoint that you can use to send an email such
as this one: `https://formsubmit.co`

You can read through the documentation for more information. But here is
a little snippet that you can use:

```
<!--
*Provide your email address on action attribute
*The email you provide on action attribute will be the one to receive an email.
-->
<form action="'https://formsubmit.co/yourEmail@email.com" method="POST">
   <input name="email" type="email" required>
   <!-- You can add more input/fields, this message input is just to notify you about the subscribers-->
   <input hidden name="message" value="Hey! I want to subscribe on your news letter." type="text">
   
   <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is so great! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in the front end. You have to do this server side.

The only thing possible with pure javascript is bringing up the users default email client with a predefined message. But the user will still have to send it.

```js
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent any mail you have to use server side function, But javascript/jquery is client side script.

you can do this make a ajax request and send all data then send mail with your need.

Answer (score 0):

javascript or jquery cant provide that facility because it will be loaded and executed in client side browser. To send a mail you need protocal(SMTP) and server help.
Solution:

1.Use AJAX and serialize your form elements and post it to server file

2.Create your server side file and in that get the posted value and send a mail.ex: php(server side)

```
 mail("youremailaddress@gmail.com", "subject" .$email, $message);
```

Need more stuff see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300470/jquery-ajax-form-using-mail-php-script-sends-email-but-post-data-from-html-fo) ..

Comment: I've tried this solution but couldn't get it to work. I've opened new question to avoid confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096313/submiting-form-to-email-address