# Submiting form to email address

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to have entered email address delivered to my inbox so that when user enters his email in form, I get an email notification about it.

This is the php:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $email = $_POST['email'];

//send email
    mail("email@email.com", "Newsletter Signup:" .$email);
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong since it's not working atm ?

Comment: mail("email@email.com", "Newsletter Signup:", $email);

Comment: All on the same domain? If you remove the _POST check and open the url  in a browser with ?email=xxx does it work?

Comment: Removing the "." as suggested by Daan makes it work but the email now comes blank, not showing the entered email address.

Comment: @AlexK. PHP file is hosted externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the problem with this question**

The reason why your mails won't be delivered can be really **anything**. Check the environments of your mailserver and your webserver.

- Check your Email Account for spam filters
- Maybe your internet provider is blocking the email because of unverified sender address
- Firewalls problems
- etc...

**How to solve the problem**

Since the mail() function implementation in php is returning a boolean, you can use this return value to detect an error:

```
<?php [...]

$email = $_POST['email'];

$success = mail("email@email.com", "Newsletter Signup:", $email);

if (!$success) {
  $error = error_get_last();
  var_export($error);
}

[...] ?>
```

Maybe this will help you to locate the problem.