# Contact form (Wordpress) won't submit

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email, akismet

I am creating a theme in Wordpress, using [an Akismet form](http://blog.pnapieralski.com/php/spam-proof-contact-form-with-php-akismet/) and a [jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300470/jquery-ajax-form-using-mail-php-script-sends-email-but-post-data-from-html-fo) script.  I have modified all of the relevant areas to integrate into my Wordpress site, even using the Akismet API key that is already there.  Here is my code:

**Form**

```
<form method="post" id="contact_form">
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1"/> <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" tabindex="2"/> <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  <input id="website" type="text" name="website" tabindex="3" value="http://" /> <label for="website">Website</label>
  <textarea id="message" tabindex="4" rows="10" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send E-mail" tabindex="5" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#contact_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/inc/email.php",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
    require "Akismet.class.php";
    function send_mail( $name, $email, $website, $ip, $is_spam, $message) {
        $subject = '';
        if( $is_spam == true )
            $subject = "[SPAM?]"; 
        $subject .= "[Your_site.com] E-mail received from ".$author_name."//".$author_email."//".$ip;

        wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), $subject, $message, $name.' <'.$email.'>');
    }
    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $wp_key = get_option( 'wordpress_api_key' );
        $our_url = get_bloginfo( 'url' );

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $website = $_POST['website'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $akismet = new Akismet($our_url, $wp_key);
        $akismet->setCommentAuthor($name);
        $akismet->setCommentAuthorEmail($email);
        $akismet->setCommentAuthorURL($website);
        $akismet->setCommentContent($message);
        $akismet->setUserIP($ip);

        send_mail( $name, $email, $website, $ip, $akismet->isCommentSpam(), $message);
    }
```

When I submit the form, it processes something and redirects me to a 404 page, even though the URL is the same as the contact page.  The email also does not send.  Could someone help me with where the issue may lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is going to submit before the ajax call even gets a look in. Use `preventDefault` to stop the default action

```
$(function() {
    $("#contact_form").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       ...
```

**Edit**

I just notice you return false, which *should* acheive the same result, but sometimes I have notice it does not

You could try `preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and it has prevented the redirect to a 404 page, but the form still isn't sending messages. I have even attempted to directly insert the email address and API key into the PHP script, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear this answer solved the `Contact form (Wordpress) won't submit` problem. I would suggest that you post a new question related the the email not sending issue. Please remember to accept the answer

Comment: I did mention that the email wouldn't send in my original question.  Whilst your answer was very helpful and prevented the 404 error, it has only solved half the issue that I posted.

Comment: I understand, and the reason why I suggest you post a new question is so that you have more chance of getting useful assistance. The question title now bears little relevance to the problem that you're now having, (email not sending with php) - just trying to be helpful

Comment: That makes more sense, and you do have a very good point. Thank you.