# Bootstrap submit to email

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to put a simple contact form on bootstrap that sends it to the email:

iwantyourbod@iwantyourbod.com

I know this has been answered many times and ive gone through the links and tried many things. I have learned i probably need ajax (dont know what that is) and PHP(super rusty). 
It hasnt helped... I am posting my code so someone could dumb it down even more because i dont honestly get it. But i have some amount of it handled.

I also am using this [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

and also if possible explain/help me out with validating the first and last name and to show its success check mark upon entering info on input because I have it working for the email portion but for the first and last name no check marks. I would like it to show up after 2 characters or if they have a standard rule that would be fine as well just want the validations to pop up

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
      <div class="row form-group has-feedback">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="John" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="inputLastName" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Doe" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>

        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Invalid Email Entry" required>

          <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is that related to PHP at all?

Comment: Did you even try to develop the PHP code to send the email?

Comment: What are you doing that is supposed to **send an e-mail**? Twitter Bootstrap does not have anything to do with e-mails, but PHP **would**.  What do you have from a PHP standpoint? Have you looked at something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382062/870729

Comment: I would also goto the jQuery website and read up on Ajax methods (Ajax, Get, Post) since bootstrap uses jquery. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/  This post might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300470/jquery-ajax-form-using-mail-php-script-sends-email-but-post-data-from-html-fo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)