# On form submission hide the form diva and send an email using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

My objective is to send the form data as an email using php and the form div should get replaced by another div. I have done hiding the div part using jquery but not able to send and email. I have also written the code to send email but my issue is how to call the file which has email sending code.

My form code:

```
<form method="post" id="formsub">
   <div id="form">
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="button" id="addbut" name="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control">
       </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

My code to hide the div and tried  form submission script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#addbut").on('click', function() {
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "fromemail.php",
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          success: function(){
           $("#form").hide();
           $("#address").show();
          }
        });
       });
    }); 
 </script>
```

My php email sending code:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']){
        $to = "akhil@redd.xyz"; // this is your Email address
        $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $subject = "Spots Contact";
        $message = $first_name . ", with " . $phone . "has enquired for the service";

        $headers = "From:" . $from;

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

       if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
       {
            echo "<script>alert('We will contact you shortly');</script>";
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I need a solution not edit suggestions. Please urgent

Comment: What error you are getting ? are you getting post data in "fromemail.php" file ?

Comment: I am not getting an error I am not able to call the file fromemail.php. How to do that using script

Comment: Please check the code below. It is still not working. Now I am getting not response @RakhiPrajapati

Answer (score 0):

Give file name in form action attribute :

```
<form id="formsub" method="post" action="fromemail.php">
```

and do ajax code like this :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var form=$("#formsub");
    $("#addbut").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:form.attr("action"),
        data:$("#formsub").serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);  
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error in console:  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Error is because of not getting file. Try giving path using base url of your project. var base_url = "http://localhost/projectname/". then url in ajax as base_url+"filename.php"

Comment: This is the error I am getting: POST http://www.3ding.in/spots/fromemail.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
send @ jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ designkari:477
dispatch @ jquery-2.2.1.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.2.1.min.js:3

Answer (score 0):

@Rakhi..

Is this correct??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function() {
    var form=$("#formsub");
    var base_url = "www.3ding.in/spots/";
    $("#addbut").on('click', function() {

    $("#form").hide();
        $("#address").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "fromemail.php",
        data: $("#formsub").serialize(),
        success: function(response){
        alert(1);
        console.log(response);


        }






    });



    });


});
```

Comment: Yes, its correct, for finding **base_url**  use :- "<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" and try to give the correct path of file(fromemail.php).

Comment: Please refer this link for more understanding (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300470/jquery-ajax-form-using-mail-php-script-sends-email-but-post-data-from-html-fo)