# The code "works", but does not send the email

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

The code "works" as in it gives the correct message when fields are filled out, but it does not send the email. Could this be something I need to set on go-daddy's end? or is the code wrong. I am new to all of this and still learning how everything works.

I am building a site for my wife and am very new, I got this info from a great video on you tube because the classes I am taking have not gotten this far. I am still on CSS and Bootstrap.

I put the php on a page in the root folder, I have double checked the file name. main_parser.php

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['p']) ){
    $n = $_POST['n']; 
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $to = "redacted@gmail.com";
    $from = $e;
    $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$p.'</p>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>


--------------------------------------------

<script>
  function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
  function submitForm(){
    _("main-submit").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
    formdata.append( "p", _("p").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "main_parser.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("main-form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("n").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("main-submit").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
  }
  </script>


--------------------------------------------------------------------

<form id="main-form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">

        <div class="col-lg-4 space label-adj">
          <label for="" class="form-label">JOIN THE CAMPAIGN TODAY!</label>
        </div>


      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 space">
          <input id="n" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 space">
          <input id="e" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 space">
          <input id="p" type="Phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-row space">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <button id="main-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block submit-b"><span id="status"></span>Submit</button>

        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I sure hope you didn't just post someone's *real* email address in a public forum like that...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks, I've just gone ahead and removed it

Comment: @Saino_Moore does it echo the 'success' message? It could be getting blocked by spam filters at Google Mail's end, there's many things at play here.

Comment: Where is `$email` set? Empty `From` header might throw a spam filter.

Comment: I get success message, just no email. I had found the error in $email after I posted here, sorry didn't have time to update before people answered. You guys are amazing. I have it hosted on go-daddy so it's not local. Nothing showing up in the spam folder on the email address either.

Comment: Welcome,  bear. First, You've posted your question well, in my opinion. Your question reads well and I like your sample code. I was wondering why you aren't using jquery as well. I am used to seeing something along these lines: 
{$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
}
Check out this other StackOverflow article: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300470/jquery-ajax-form-using-mail-php-script-sends-email-but-post-data-from-html-fo

Comment: Thanks Su Llewellyn, I am still learning. Working my way through a course on udemy and have just started Javascript, Jquery is still 6+ hours away, and at my current rate of completion that = 3-4 days at the least.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is probably somewhere else because ...

> `mail()`:
>
> Returns `TRUE` if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, `FALSE` otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does **NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.**

[php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)